# How to make a backwards "\in"

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

Hopefully this question has a one word answer!

I want to be able to write a backwards epsilon of the sort used for set membership in mathmode. Lets say this command was called "\backin", then here would be an example use:

```
\Theta(f(n)) \backin g(n) \in O(h(n))
```

To say that g(n) is in both \Theta(f(n)) and O(h(n)), but with an ordering that kind of lays them out nicely in one line in a sort of greater-than-less-than analogy.

Do you know an easy way to do this? I searched around but could not find an example.

Comment: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org) makes it really easy to find such symbols.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of "how to look up a math(s) symbol".  My reason being that things like Detexify are _so_ much better for this sort of thing than a Q&A set up so I want to be sure that anyone happening on this question who _doesn't_ already know about these resources gets clearly directed there.  Closing as a duplicate seems a clear way to lead them there.

Comment: @Andrew, I am not sure I agree with you. Someone using google might be directed to this website, which not only would promote Tex.StackExchange, but would also help them find detexify.

Comment: @Vivi: "Close as duplicate" does **not** say "This question shouldn't be here".  I certainly hope that Google does direct that person here, but then I hope that that person can **easily** find detexify.  "Close as duplicate" is, I think, merely a way to harden the trail from this question to the more general "How do I find" question.  _This is not a bad question._  I'm merely thinking about "housekeeping" and what's best for others coming along later.

Comment: I also don't mind the question being closed. I searched this site for what I would expect to be search terms associated with my question, but did not come across detexify. This was mostly because I did not search for a general "look up a symbol" question because I had already checked the standard references I usually use for symbols and could not see "\ni" there. Thanks!

Answer (score 80):

Did you try `\ni` (\in spelled backwards)?

Comment: UNfortunately, neither of `\niton` or `\notni` are defined for a backwards `\notin`...

Comment: "\not\ni" works well.

Comment: so does "\not\owns"

Comment: @FedericoPoloni What's the Monty Python reference, again?

Comment: @taninamdar Only a weak one... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_who_say_Ni

Answer (score 14):

LaTeX has built-in support for that in the form of `\ni`:

```
$\Theta(f(n)) \ni g(n) \in O(h(n))$
```

[image: Backwards \in=\ni]

As a resource, Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) is always a good place to start for [a vast array of mathematical symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\backin}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-180}{$\in$}}%
\begin{document}
\[
   \backin
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: in such caeses it makes more sense to use `\reflectbox{$\in$}` instead

Comment: Didn't know `\reflectbox` either. Thanks for point that out.

Comment: @Peter: you're missing a `\mathrel` around the whole content of the macro to get correct spacing. Also, this kind of solution won't work correctly in subscripts unless you use `\mathchoice`.